# I'm getting "jumpy" loadings in rollapply PCA in R. Can I fix it?

Tags: r, pca, moving-window

I have 10 years of daily returns data for 28 different currencies. I wish to extract the first principal component, but rather than operate PCA on the whole 10 years, I want to rollapply a 2 year window, because the currencies' behaviours evolve and so I wish to reflect this. However I have a major problem, that is that both the `princomp()` and `prcomp()` functions will often jump from positive to negative loadings in adjacent PCA analyses (ie 1 day apart). Have a look at the loading chart for the EUR currency:

[image]

Clearly I can't use this because adjacent loadings will jump from positive to negative, so my series which uses them will be erroneous. Now take a look at the absolute value of the EUR currency loading:

[image]

The problem is of course that I still cannot use this because you can see from the top chart that the loading does go from negative to positive and back at times, a characteristic which I need to preserve.

Is there any way I can get around this problem? Can I force the eigenvector orientation to always be the same in adjacent PCAs?

By the way this problem also occurs with the FactoMineR PCA() function. The code for the rollapply is here:

```
rollapply(retmat, windowl, function(x) 
  summary(princomp(x))$loadings[, 1], by.column = FALSE, 
  align = "right") -> princomproll
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by eigenvector "orientation"? As far as I know, there is no such thing that is *intrinsic to the data.* (That's one reason why different software will produce different normalized eigenvectors.) So it sounds like you're asking for something that does not exist and is meaningless.

Comment: Well on one day I'll get loadings like this:
EUR -0.2  ZAR +0.8  USD +0.41 ..... 28 currencies.
And the next day I'll get
EUR +0.21 ZAR -0.79 USD -0.4 etc. So the axis that the PCA has chosen to rotate the data onto is oriented exactly the opposite way on day 2, compared with day 1. That is causing these loading jumps and I wish to avoid it, somehow......Apologies if my terminology is misleading. I understand that the PCA code doesn't really care about the axis orientation as long as it is consistent across loadings *on one day*, but I need it to be consistent across multiple days.

Comment: keeping in mind that from one day to the next, given a rolling 2 year window on daily data, we should have very, very similar PCA.

Comment: I think the reason that you have a problem is that this rollapply idea doesn't make sense.  I have no solution other than to look for something different that may achieve your goals (not sure what they are) and is sensible.

Comment: `EUR -0.2 ZAR +0.8 USD +0.41` and `EUR +0.21 ZAR -0.79 USD -0.4` _are_ very very similar. You simply invert sign in any of the two results.

Comment: Why does it not make sense that the euro, a currency which tended to be strong in periods of risk aversion, now tends to be weak in the same periods of risk aversion? We have gone through a major financial crisis, and the behaviour of some currencies is now different from how they operated pre-crisis. A 10y PCA will clearly not identify this change of behaviour whereas a 2y rolling window clearly does. I could identify this change using rolling correlations on the first PC but I would probably get a much weaker first PC anyway and so this rolling PCA technique I think is superior?

Comment: I think, a basic requirement to get the rolled eigenvectors in a common vectorspace ("can I force the eigenvectors...same orientation") should be a common measuring over all samplings. That means in my opinion, you should assume ratio scale for your measurings and prevent the rolling factor-analyses to re-center and re-scale the current sub-sample ( so this means also to use a rolling covariance matrix instead of a correlation matrix besides the preventing to recentering around the dynamical means). Did you consider this?

Comment: @ Gottfried Helms: Gottfried, the above graphs do use a rolling covariance matrix as that is the default for the princomp function (cor = FALSE). Moreover I have already scaled the variables because as you will note, I am using "EUR" only, not "EURUSD" or some other crossrate price, because I have created variance and scale normalised indices for each currency themselves derived from PCA. So yes, all my samples across currencies use a common and comparable scaling in both magnitude and variance. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Whenever the plot jumps too much, reverse the orientation.**  One effective criterion is this: compute the total amount of jumps on all the components.  Compute the total amount of jumps if the next eigenvector is negated.  If the latter is less, negate the next eigenvector.

Here's an implementation.  (I am not familiar with `zoo`, which might allow a more elegant solution.)

```
require(zoo)
amend <- function(result) {
  result.m <- as.matrix(result)
  n <- dim(result.m)[1]
  delta <- apply(abs(result.m[-1,] - result.m[-n,]), 1, sum)
  delta.1 <- apply(abs(result.m[-1,] + result.m[-n,]), 1, 
                   sum)
  signs <- c(1, cumprod(rep(-1, n-1) ^ (delta.1 <= delta)))
  zoo(result * signs)
}
```

As an example, let's run a random walk in an orthogonal group and jitter it a little for interest:

```
random.rotation <- function(eps) {
  theta <- rnorm(3, sd=eps)
  matrix(c(1, theta[1:2], -theta[1], 1, theta[3], 
                 -theta[2:3], 1), 3)
}
set.seed(17)
n.times <- 1000
x <- matrix(1., nrow=n.times, ncol=3)
for (i in 2:n.times) {
  x[i,] <- random.rotation(.05) %*% x[i-1,]
}
```

Here's the rolling PCA:

```
window <- 31
data <- zoo(x)
result <- rollapply(data, window, 
  function(x) summary(princomp(x))$loadings[, 1], 
               by.column = FALSE, align = "right")
plot(result)
```

[image: Original]

Now the fixed version:

```
plot(amend(result))
```

[image: Amended]

Comment: I upvoted this great answer a long time ago, but now came back to it because I had to implement something similar myself. The approach that I chose (before looking in your post again) was to go through all timepoints $t_i$ and compute the dot product between the leading eigenvector $\mathbf v_{i+1}$ (first PC axis) on the timestep $i+1$ and the eigenvector $\mathbf v_{i}$ on the previous step $i$. If this dot product is close to $1$, do nothing. It it is close to $-1$, flip the direction of $\mathbf v_{i+1}$. Your algorithm seems to be a bit different. Would it work the same way?

Comment: @amoeba Although I'm not quite sure exactly what you are doing, it sounds like some of the ideas discussed in David J. Harris's answer and the comments following it.  See, in particular, my comment at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34396/im-getting-jumpy-loadings-in-rollapply-pca-in-r-can-i-fix-it/34401?noredirect=1#comment68515_34399 .

Comment: David suggested to fix a sign of one coordinate of the $\mathbf v$ vector (eigenvector $\approx$ loading vector). I agree with you that this is not enough. Moreover, I **fully** agree with you that *"The trick is at each time to choose the orientation that creates the least disturbance in the vector of loadings from the previous time"*. So my approach is to measure this disturbance by looking at the angle between new loading vector and previous loading vector. Flip the new vector if the angle is around $180^\circ$ (and don't flip if it is around $0^\circ$).

Comment: But after looking again at your answer, I believe our approaches are almost identical.

Comment: @amoeba The algorithms are close, but they are not the same and can produce different results.  Try yours out with the sample data produced by my code.

Comment: @whuber Alas, I am not an R user :-/ But I see the difference in algorithms; my guess is that in practice they will both work fine.

Comment: @amoeba and whuber : thanks for the answers, although there is still some issue - each algorithm requires to use two vectors to compare and assumes that first vector has correct orientation, but what if first vector is wrong and if we try to fit the rest to the first one, in this case we are inverting orientation of all correct vectors. Does anybody has solution that can check correctness of the very first vector, like it is described here - http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/3094/time-series-of-pca-sign-change-in-factor-loadings/18380#answer-18380 ?

Comment: @Art, but what does it mean for the very first vector to be "correct"? We know that the sign of this vector is arbitrary. It seems that the whole matter is only to make the signs consistent across different positions of a sliding window, but the initial sign in the first window remains arbitrary.

Comment: @amoeba : yes, I know about "arbitrary" signs, in my case I need to project source points onto selected principal component or eigen space using coefficients from eigenvector, in this case I will get mean reversal equity that always converges to zero. It means that I can buy at the bottom - and sell it on the zero level. The problem is that sometimes some assets in portfolio have a trend (long movement in some direction), e.g. EUR goes down during one month, at the same time PCA returns positive eigenvector for EUR, it is wrong, coefficient should go along the trend and be with a minus.

Comment: @Art, so as I understand it, you want to fix the sign of the component based on some external (external to PCA) preferences. This is fine, but that is how you should approach it. First do the sliding PCA thing, making sure that the signs are consistent. And then decide, based on some additional criteria, whether to flip the whole component or not. E.g. you can correlate it with the euro trend and if the correlation is negative, flip the component. Or something like that. This entirely depends on your specific application and on your domain knowledge.

Comment: I agree with @amoeba's interpretation and recommendation.

Comment: @amoeba : yes, you are right about this, although, I naively thought that there might be some generic solution that is not dependent on specific time series, something like "real orientation of the vector" :) anyway, thank you for help and suggestions

Answer (score 7):

@whuber is right that there isn't an orientation that's intrinsic to the data, but you could still enforce that your eigenvectors have positive correlation with some reference vector.

For instance, you could make the loadings for USD positive on all your eigenvectors (i.e., if USD's loading is negative, flip the signs of the entire vector). The overall direction of your vector is still arbitrary (since you could have used EUR or ZAR as your reference instead), but the first few axes of your PCA probably won't jump around nearly as much--especially because your rolling windows are so long.

Comment: Good idea.  I tried this first (probably while you were posting this answer :-).  The problem is that the other loadings can jump around.  To fix this, base the sign choice on the largest loading. Still no dice: the loadings can still jump.  The trick is at each time to choose the orientation that creates the least disturbance in the *vector* of loadings from the previous time.

Comment: @whuber Nice work.

Comment: Correct, the sign of loadings doesn't matter (orientation). Something that was not addressed was that if you perform this across different software packages, the between-package differences is that one program may result in negative(positive) signs on particular loadings while another results in positive(negative) signs for the same loadings.  Therefore, the signs of the final results in the 3-series plot above could be inverted when using another package.  The reference vector loadings could also have a sign change - and this solution would not be incorrect.

Comment: @LEP : I faced the same problem with inversion, maybe you have already found solution for this issue - how to find out that first vector is correct and make sure that the rest will be aligned to it properly - http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/3094/time-series-of-pca-sign-change-in-factor-loadings/18380#answer-18380 ?

Comment: As long as the matrix is not singular and none of the eigenvalues are zero, most algorithm results should be the same, except for a 180 degree change in the signs - which is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was to compute the L1 distance between successive eigenvectors. After normalizing this matrix I choose a z score threshold e.g. 1, so that if in any new rolling the change is above this threshold I flip the eigenvector, factors and loadings in order to have consistency in the rolling window. Personally I don't like to force given signs in some correlations since they can be very volatile depending of the macro drivers.