# How to reverse the sign of factor loadings in factor analysis?

Tags: factor-analysis

I'm doing a factor analysis and using the resulting factors in a regression. I'm using SAS. A number of the variables load positively on a factor. In order to make it easier to interpret in the final regression, it would be better if the loadings were negative.

Is there a way I can rotate the factor so the loadings are negative? Could the factors be multiplied by $-1$?

Comment: Yes: see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34396.  The SAS details, if you need them, are best asked on SO rather than here.

Comment: Yes, the loadings (and consequently the scores) of a factor can be multiplied by -1. Most FA implemementations actually do it internally: if sum of negative loadings is greater than the sum of positive ones, the sign is reverted.