# Determining the Direction of Eigenvectors in PCA

Tags: r, pca, interpretation, dimensionality-reduction, eigenvalues

I'm using R to get the principal components for several datasets.

An example result, using prcomp yields:

```
       PC1        PC2
X1 -0.7071068 -0.7071068
X2 -0.7071068  0.7071068
```

I'm then using the first principal component, from each dataset, as an input into another model (well, I plan to).

The problem is that, for interpretability, the direction of the first principal component matters. This is because I'll be multiplying my data by the components of the first eigenvector, and the direction changes the final result. (This result I also need to report).

If I get updated data, and retrain PCA, it's possible that the prcomp result could be:

```
       PC1        PC2
X1 0.7071068 -0.7071068
X2 0.7071068  0.7071068
```

And if I multiply by the first eigenvector, the result will be the additive inverse. I could just take the absolute value of the components of the first eigenvector, but this feels wrong... and also, I'm not sure about extending it to cases with more than 2 components.

(I know that if the first principal component was (0.7071068, 0.7071068), mathematically, the result would be the same; most variance explained along that line since eigenvectors multiplied by scalars are still eigenvectors.)

I'm curious if anyone has come across a similar problem, or if there is a technique for dealing with such issues?

For now, I am manually changing the direction of the first eigenvector on a case by case basis, **if needed**.

Any suggestions appreciated :)

Comment: It's not quite clear what the whole process is here. You have a bunch of datasets, you take PC1 of each, and input those to some other model. OK. What do you mean "If I get new data and rerun PCA"? Why would you get new data? Is it test data to which the model will be applied? Or is it new training data that you will use to retrain the model? In the former case you should not rerun PCA. In the latter case why do you care about signs matching to what you had before?

Comment: Sorry - that is unclear. It is new data that I'll be using to retrain (I've edited the question). I care about it, because if the sign changes, then I cannot directly compare to the previous results, if I multiply my original values by the loadings. I hope this makes sense?

Comment: I'm still not sure why (and how!) you want to compare new model to the old model. Don't think your Q is answerable without this being clear. That said, if you want to enforce consistency between signs, you can choose the sign of the new PC such that the angle with the old PC is close to 0 and not to 180 (i.e. if the angle is large -- flip the sign).

Comment: Direction (sign) is arbitrary in PCA. For convenience, often program assign sign so that in each column (component)  of the _loading_ matrix the sum is positive. I'm speaking about [loadings](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/143905/3277), while you call eigenvector entries "loadings", please mind.

Comment: @amoeba I'm looking at time series data. Each month, there will be a new set of observations. Each month, I want to retrain PCA, take the first eigenvector and reduce the dimensionality of the data down to one dimension. Since the direction of that first eigenvector is arbitrary, I could potentially see spurious large changes.

Comment: @ttnphns Thanks you for clearing up that terminology. I have edited my question appropriately.

Comment: You can't take absolute values, that can change the span of the vector. You can multiply by a constant though (like `-1`). You could choose a normalization that always keeps the same direction (e.g. magnitude of 1 and positive first element, or first element equal to +1) but since you're claiming that the direction matters in your problem, it implies there is one correct normalization that is right for your problem.

Comment: I see! You should have mentioned time series. Then it's almost a duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34396.

Comment: @amoeba Thanks - I'm busy going through that answer. It makes sense, but I may have some implementation difficulties; in particular, I'm not sure I'll be able to store the previous PCA results.