# Why does PCA result change drastically with a slight change in the input?

Tags: python, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I am using PCA to reduce an Nx3 array to an Nx2 array. This is mainly because the PCA transformation (Nx2 matrix) is invariant to the rotations or translations performed on the original Nx3 array. Let's take the following as an example.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
a = np.array([[0.5  , 0.5  , 0.5  ],
              [0.332, 0.456, 0.751],
              [0.224, 0.349, 0.349],
              [0.112, 0.314, 0.427]])
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
print(pca.fit_transform(a))
```

The following is the output. Note that we get the same output with `print(pca.fit_transform(a-L))`, `L` being any number, due to translational invariance. Same with rotations.

```
[[ 0.16752654  0.15593431]
 [ 0.20568992 -0.14688601]
 [-0.16899598  0.06364857]
 [-0.20422047 -0.07269687]]
```

Now, I give a very small perturbation (~1%) to the array `a` and perform PCA.

```
a_p = np.array([[0.51 , 0.53 , 0.52 ],
       [0.322, 0.452, 0.741],
       [0.217, 0.342, 0.339],
       [0.116, 0.31 , 0.417]])
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
print(pca.fit_transform(a_p))
```

The result is as follows. This is quite different from the PCA of the original array.

```
 [[-0.2056024 , -0.14346977]
 [-0.18563578  0.15627932]
 [ 0.17974942 -0.07001969]
 [ 0.21148876  0.05721014]]
```

I expected the PCA transformation of the perturbed array to be very similar to that of the original array, but the percentage change is huge. Why is this? Is there any way I could obtain a very similar PCA transformation for a slightly perturbed/shaked array?

I understand that I can get a similar PCA by performing only transform operation in the second case (e.g. `pca.transform(a_p)`), however, in this case, I lose rotational and translational invariance w.r.t. `a_p`.

The question is originally related to crystallography and my requirement is that the PCA (or whatever) transformation should not change significantly to a small change in the input as well as it should be invariant to the rotations and transformations of the input. Can anyone explain the above or suggest me an alternative method which serves my purpose?

**EDIT**

As mentioned in a comment I will try to explain the actual problem I am trying to solve and the properties of a good solution. Basically, I want to obtain a 2-dimensional representation of a 3D crystal structure (periodic unit cell shown below). This 2D representation should be invariant to the rotations or translations of the original 3D structure (because it's the same crystal anyway).

[image: crystal unit cell]

Let's say we have a unit cell with N number of atoms. The fractional coordinates of selected 4 atoms are indicated above. I first represent this crystal structure by an Nx3 matrix (`A`), 3 columns being x,y & z coordinates.

\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0.5&0.5&0.5\\..&..&..\end{bmatrix}

Now, I want to find a rotationally and translationally independent representation of `A`. To do this, I perform PCA on `A` to obtain an Nx2 matrix (`B`). Due to the nature of PCA, I get rotational and translational invariance (i.e. `B = PCA(A) = PCA(A-L) = PCA(`[`A_rotated_by_x_degrees`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802577/rotation-of-3d-vector)`)` where `L` and `x` are any numbers). However, here's my problem.

A small change in matrix `A` results in a completely different principle components (`B`). For example, if I change only the first element of first row from 0 to 0.5, the PCA result changes dramatically resulting in a completely new `B`. I want this change in `B` to reflect the slight change that I made in `A` (e.g. preserve the correlation between other unchanged atom coordinates/retain the other rows as they are, if possible). Can I expect this from PCA? Could you suggest a better solution? It doesn't necessarily have to be PCA.

**EDIT2:**

Following @whuber's comment I'd like to show how I verified rotational invariance of PCA ($\mathbb{R}^2$) for any rotation in the 3D structure ($\mathbb{R}^3$). Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong. The code below is partly adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802577/rotation-of-3d-vector) SO thread. Using the above array `a` as the input;

```
from numpy import cross, eye, dot
from scipy.linalg import expm, norm

def M(axis, theta):
    return expm(cross(eye(3), axis/norm(axis)*theta))

axis = [4,3,-1] # can be rotated around any axis
theta = 1.2 # can be any rotation
M0 = M(axis, theta)

a_rotated = []  # 'a' rotated by theta radians around the given axis
for vec in a:
    vec_r = dot(M0,vec)  # rotate each individual vector
    a_rotated.append(vec_r)

a_rotated = np.array(a_rotated)
print(a_rotated)
```

`a_rotated` is as follows;

```
[[ 0.8410511  -0.05506857  0.19899872]
 [ 0.80627738 -0.30144367  0.37577851]
 [ 0.49270955 -0.05237642  0.21970892]
 [ 0.42659993 -0.14804179  0.29927434]]
```

Now, I obtain the PCA of `a_rotated`.

```
print(pca.fit_transform(a_rotated))
```

This gives;

```
[[ 0.16752654  0.15593431]
 [ 0.20568992 -0.14688601]
 [-0.16899598  0.06364857]
 [-0.20422047 -0.07269687]]
```

which is exactly the same to the PCA of array `a`. Doesn't this mean PCA is invariant to the rotations of the input?

Comment: If $v$ is an eigenvector to $A$, then $-v$ is also an eigenvector of $A$. If we account for reversing the signs, then the differences are not that dramatic. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88880/does-the-sign-of-scores-or-of-loadings-in-pca-or-fa-have-a-meaning-may-i-revers

Comment: adding to @Sycorax comment: statsmodels' PCA doesn't try to get consistent signage of PCs coefficients, which is unfortunate. you get signs wildly flipping at smallest changes of inputs, which is ridiculous, but a par for the course given that it's Python software

Comment: Hmm.. that makes sense. In this case I am helpless cz my further processing requires the sign of the PCA components to be consistent. Do you know of any python package (or any package) that provides consistent signage for PCA?

Comment: @AchinthaIhalage There are some suggestions in this thread. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34396/im-getting-jumpy-loadings-in-rollapply-pca-in-r-can-i-fix-it

Comment: You've stated that the PCA solution should be invariant to rotations of the input, but because PCA is itself a way to find a certain rotation of the input data, it seems like you've already got a solution. Likewise, PCA centers (translates) the input to have 0 mean. Can you [edit] your post to explain what problem you're trying to solve, and give a detailed explanation of what properties a good solution would have, and why PCA is deficient? Or is the core of the question addressed by the fact that eigenvalues are only identified up to a nonzero scalar multiple?

Comment: @Sycorax thanks for the insights. I have edited the question. Let me know if this makes sense and if there's  a possible solution to this problem.

Comment: Your problem isn't soluble: there's no such thing as a projection from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is invariant under all rotations of $\mathbb{R}^3.$

Comment: @whuber I have edited the question showing how I verified the rotational invariance of PCA. Could you please have a look? Also I don't require the resulting rotational invariant representation to be $\mathbb{R}^2$. It may have any number of dimensions. Is this soluble in this case?

Comment: The PCA is invariant, by construction: but that has nothing to do with your projection into two dimensions.  I guess I'm having trouble figuring out what you're trying to accomplish.  It looks like the initial guess by @Sycorax might be correct and that your solution is contained in the thread they referenced.  Otherwise, your complaint seems to be that PCA depends on its inputs--but it's hard to see how that's a problem.

Comment: Well I need to represent matrix `A` above with some matrix `B` and `B` should not change even if I rotate each (x,y,z) vector available in `A` by any degree $\alpha$.

Comment: The PCA gives the matrix `B` that I am looking for. However, if I introduce a very small change to the input matrix `A` the matrix `B` changes dramatically. I need the change in `B` to be more "uniform" rather than being completely different to the initial `B`. This was my problem with PCA.

Comment: I think you aren't comparing your outputs correctly.  In your original example, the outputs are not "quite different:" they are comparable. The threads we have referenced point out that you must be willing to (a) locally permute the principal components (to account for reorderings of their eigenvalues) and (b) negate any PC, because PCs are defined only up to sign.  When you account for this, the two matrices are quite close.  This again suggests that all your problems will be solved by studying the threads we have linked to.